# Griffon mvc groups not being created

Tags: groovy, griffon

I'm experimenting with Griffon and MVC groups  .. I have a view which i want to include in a main view ..

In my 'subview' I have .

```
package sequenceproto

productionPanel = panel() {
    label('Production Line View')
}
```

In the controller which creates the MVC group for the above view  I have ..

```
 void mvcGroupInit(Map args)

    createMVCGroup('productionLine', 'prodLine')
```

To access the label in my 'main' view I have ..

```
  widget(app.views.prodLine.productionPanel, constraints: 'width 35%')
```

When I run my app I get a NPE ..

Cannot get property 'productionPanel' on null object

If I place a println in the mvcGroupInit it doesn't seem to be called BEFORE the view is created ..

What can I be doing wrong  ??

Griffon 1.5 / jdk 1.7  ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer is to change the order of creation in the Application.groovy file to ensure the controller is created BEFORE the view  .. The default creation order is model/view/controller (which contradicts the gia book p121 which says its model/controller/view .. though this itself is contradicted on page 147 of the same book)